# How to merge two or more multi dimensional arrays in PHP to make it one array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need a function to solve this issue.

Example:

```
$ar1 = array("alpha" => array("A","B","C","D"), ...);
$ar2 = array("numerics" => array("1","2","3","4"), ...);

$output = merge_arrays($ar1,$ar2);
print_r($output);
```

Result:

```
array("A","B","C","D","1","2","3","4");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      $output = call_user_func_array('array_merge',
      array_values(array_merge_recursive($ar1,$ar2)));

      print_r($output);
```

Comment: probably the best solution

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge this 2 arrays like this:

```
$new_array = array_merge($ar1['alpha'], $ar2['numerics']);
```

In this way you will have an array like the one you describe.

You can check more information about `array_merge` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: I need it without specify the array keys.

Comment: its not a generic answer

Comment: @Adnan30pk You have only 1 level of dimension and you want to merge only that? You didn't specify exactly what you have, only an example and on that example I created the answer. Please add more information so I know exactly what you need.